# Knapsack algorithm: strange behavior with pown() on the gpu

Tags: opencl

The version on the CPU OCL produces right results, where the GPU OCL in some places gives slightly different results in some places that after all influence the correctness of the result. I have debugged on Intel OCL SDK where I get right results. I haven't spotted any race condition or concurrent access to the memory. This problem has appeared after I have introduced in the kernel (one line of code) pown function.

```
void kernel knapsack(global int *input_f, global int *output_f, global uint *m_d,  int cmax, int weightk, int pk, int maxelem, int i){

int c = get_global_id(0)+cmax;

if(get_global_id(0)<maxelem){
    if(input_f[c] < input_f[c - weightk] + pk){
        output_f[c] = input_f[c - weightk] + pk;
        m_d[c-1] = pown(2.0,i); *//previous version: m_d[c-1] = 1;*
    } 
    else{
    output_f[c] = input_f[c];

    }   
 }
}
```

The purpose of pown is to compress the m_d buffer which holds the outcomes.

```
For example 
1 0 1 0    2^0+2^2, 2^1, 2^0, 2^1  
0 1 0 1 =>
1 0 0 0
```

On the gpu I get something like this:

```
    2^0+2^2, 2^1, 2^0+2^2, 2^1  in the 
    3rd column I access to pown one more again, when I'm not supposed to.
```

This gives me that "slight" different result.
    [Here you can find full code](https://github.com/nico-mkhatvari/OpenCL/blob/ShortCode/Knapsack%20OpenCL/knapsack_main.cpp)

***This work is based on this article***:

- [Solving knapsack problems on GPU by V. Boyera, D. El Baza,  M. Elkihel](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01152223/document)
- related work: [Accelerating the knapsack problem on GPUs by Bharath Suri](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:439054/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

Comment: Could you give us some examples for "slightly different results". Could these be rounding errors resulting from (hidden) decimal calculations (especially in `pown()`)? 
Please give it a try with `1 << i`instead of `pown(2.0, i)` .

Comment: Taking the example described above on the CPU m_d will contain: 5,2,1,2 where the GPU: 5,2, 5! (instead of 1), 2 I'm using OCL 1.2 bitwise operations are not defined.